# Rails model save first, then crashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question. I'm parsing content using Nokogiri and my objective is to process this content and insert in the database.

Table_rows contains parsed tr/tr elements and then I do Nokogiri's node.content.to_a to get the td values I want.

(note: I need this column rec_id because I don't know yet how to force id value when I insert hehehehe)

The code below generates an exception when it tries to save

```
  table_rows.each do |row|
    rec_id = row.content.to_a[0].strip.to_i

    if MyModelName.where(:rec_id => rec_id) == []
      MyModelName.init_from_array(row.content.to_a).save
    end

  end
```

init_from_array contains simple code like this:

```
def self.init_from_array(array)
  @mymodelname = MyModelName.new
  @mymodelname.field1 = array[0].strip #strip to avoid any empty
  @mymodelname.field2 = array[1].strip
  #and so on...
  @mymodelname
end
```

Inside controller I'm just calling this method between a begin and rescue. MyModelName don't have any validation for now.

What I'm doing wrong to get this behavior - it generates a "cannot rollback, no transaction is active" but it saves the record to the database.

edit:

here's the exception

SQLite3::SQLException: cannot rollback - no transaction is active from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:97:in close' from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:97:inprepare' from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in execute' from

Comment: What is the exception? This will help TONS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

The problem was with my migration file. Everything ran without problems but I had 1 migration for table creation and then more 3 migrations that added fields to this model. I don't know yet how or why but I deleted all the migrations and started from scratch and now it saves without that error.

Thanks